# How can I store the random numbers outputed by my funtion?

Tags: c++

at the moment I'm trying to add up the numbers for my hand and the hit cards, the issue is I created a function for my random number generator so that I can keep calling it into my dice game and the blackjack game, I would normally add the number generator to a variable and call it a day but I made it into a function instead. I am still new to c++.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void RandomNumber() { cout << (rand() % 10) + 1; }

void blackjack(int total) {
    int startstakes = 15;
    int stakes;
    int hand;

    cout << "Welcome to the Blackjack(21) table\n"
         << "How much are you adding to your initial 15 chip stake - ";

    cin >> stakes;

    cout << "New stake - " << stakes + 15 << " remaining chips - "
         << total - (stakes + 15) << endl;

    cout << "Here is your hand - ";

    RandomNumber();
    cout << " and ";
    RandomNumber();

    cout << "Hit me cards: 0 - 0 - 0\n"
         << "Total = ";

    system("pause>0");
}

int main() {
    int total = 0;
    int choice;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    cout << "Welcome to Royal Casino!!!, How much money do you wish to "
            "convert? ";

    cin >> total;

    cout << "Excelent you currently have " << total << " Chips.\n"
         << "Let's Begin!\n\n"
         << "We have to tables available today\n";

    cout << "1) Blackjack (21)\n"
         << "2) Dice\n"
         << "Both have an entry fee of 15 Chips\n"
         << "Select a table - ";

    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1) {
        blackjack(total);
    }

    if (choice == 2) {
        dice();
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Consider modifying your function to *return* a number instead of printing it.

Comment: It's slightly unfortunate that we say "output" about both what a program prints to the console and what a function returns to its caller, but you seem to have confused them.

Answer (score 3):

So the issue is that you should **return** the value instead of printing it. Like this (note the return type has changed from `void` to `int`)

```
int RandomNumber() {
    return (rand() % 10) + 1;
}
```

A function which returns a value is much more flexible than a function which prints a value.

Now you can use a function call `RandomNumber()` pretty much the same way as a variable. E.g.

```
cout << RandomNumber() << " and " << RandomNumber();
```

or

```
int var = RandomNumber();
```

Comment: this looks like it should be a comment rather than an answer